# Dynamic RADIO option Sub-Group in PHP - table wrapper issue

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

I had created a PHP form that is database-driven and populates the questions dynamically so far with great success. Unfortunately, there is a new issue that I cannot seem to get my head around...

The problem I am having is getting the "blue table title header" to properly display. As I render the form, it looks like this...

[image: dynamic form]

**BUT, I want it to look like this:**

[image: dynamic form]

this is a simplified version my code:

```
// Connect to the database
-- insert connection code here --

// SQL Query to get question 
-- insert query code here --

//initialize form
echo '<form name="surveyForm" method="post" action="submit.php">' . "\n";

//begin display of form questions
while($row=mssql_fetch_array($result)){
    //display question
    echo $row['question'];

    //determine question sub-form elements
    if($row['questionType'] == 4) { //this is for a radio-button group
        echo ('<table>
               <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</td>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
               </tr>');
     }   

    //sub-query for question form elements
    -- insert sub-query form element code here --

    while($subrow=mssql_fetch_array($subresult)){ 
        //display the question form element
        $formType = $subrow['formType'];
        $formNameAttribute = $subrow['formName'];
        $formClassAttribute = $subrow['formClass'];
        -- etc. ---

        echo $htmlBuild = '<input type="$formType" name="$formNameAttribute" class="$formClassAttribute"';
        -- etc. ---

        //If RADIO-BUTTON GROUP
        -- insert radio button display code here --

    }

    if($row['questionType'] == 4) {
        echo '</tr></table>';
    }
}   
//close out form
echo ('<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" name="submitBtn" /> 
       <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset Form" />');
```

But as you can see, if I try to add a table header, I am not sure how to make that sub-group radio button table header from not repeating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question....turns out that I put the header in the wrong loop!